# Google cloud storage, Cache-Control

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I tried to set Cache-Control header for Google Cloud Storage bucket. It gives me `400: Invalid argument error` without any explanation what exactly wrong. Any ideas?

Example:

```
gsutil setmeta -R -h 'Cache-Control:public, max-age=10000, no-transform' gs://example.com/stylesheets/
```

Setting metadata on `gs://example.com/stylesheets/site-77ee6060.css`
`BadRequestException: 400 Invalid argument`

Tried with different `max-age`, with or without `no-transform`, same result.
bucket is configured as website.

Comment: The Cache-Control parameters you're using are valid, and I was able to run the command above (with a collection of objects I own) successfully. Can you please send the output of the following command to gs-team@goolge.com, removing Authorization headers: gsutil -D setmeta -R -h 'Cache-Control:public, max-age=10000, no-transform' gs://example.com/stylesheets/

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I sent debug info to gs-team@goolge.com

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I am also have this issue happening on some of my files. Would it be helpful for me to send my output to the same address?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz - Does Google have any feedback on this issue?  I'm seeing the same problem with Content-Type

Comment: No, no feedback. After some time we decided to not use it anymore

Comment: Ivan - sorry, I never received the debug info you sent on Jun 25 '14. Can you please try again, and make to say this is for Mike Schwartz?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, and discovered that I did not have `OWNER` permission on the object anymore (someone else on my team had edited the object).